# Don't work my model in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I created model. My model have two source. First source is agent "Man" and second is agent "Woman". I need to divide them into two queues: in the first place only men, and second only women. I divide them by parameter sex.

[my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFhq0.png)

The problem is:
if the condition is not set, and the agents are divided by probability, then all is super, only the agents in the mix. and if to put a condition, then writes: "sex is not allowed, or it's not a field." And if one source is removed, then the condition works fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where is the actual question?

Comment: In program "Anylogic"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i see in your model that the true output of the if_else block is meant to go to the men queue.

So assuming that you really have Man and woman agents, you have to use the following condition in your select output block (if_else)

```
agent instanceof Man
```

This will be true if the agent is of the type Man and it will be false if the agent is different than Man. Check the following picture:
[image: instanceof usage]